# Determine postion of dart in dartboard

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, image-recognition

I'm new to machine learning and I want to built my first project.
I decided to write an application which determines the postion of a dart in a dartboard.
The neural network would have the following requirements:

- Mapping the images of 3 cameras to a 2D representation of the dartboard.
- Determining the amount and exact position of up to 3 different darts sticking in the dartboard.

Since I don't have prior knowledge to machine learning my question is regarding the optimal type of neural network and libaries I should look into for this project.

Thanks in advance
Jan

Comment: Are the cameras fixed relative to the dartboard or can the view of dartboard of an invidual camera change over time? For the first step you would have to find the homography matrix that maps the dartboard in the images to a 2D representation of the dartboard. You could use a neural network for this, but it might be easier to use classical computer vision techniques, especially when the position of the camera is fixed. For the second point you should probably look into object detection methods to detect the position of the darts on the dartboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into these subjects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 cameras or more then you do not need to use machine learning. The dartboard can be modeled as a plane, so you only need two cameras to identify its position. You can simply put a camera above the dartboard, and one on its right. Then you can get the horizontal position from the top camera and the vertical position from the side camera.

If you want to use machine learning for learning sake, you can do that with a single camera. Besides the lower project cost, you will also be reducing the size of the input data without losing information. I would position the camera at an angle facing the dartboard. Then you will need to follow the following steps

- Collecting data
- Labelling the data
- Building a model

#### Collecting the data

You will need to collect thousands of images of the darts in the dartboard from the camera in a fixed position.

#### Labelling the data

You will need to attribute a target with the ground truth for each image. This will consist of an (x,y) coordinate for each of the 3 darts. Our final model will have 6 outputs.

#### Building a model

For object detection in images, Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) are a good choice to start. You can build one easily by using the Keras API of TensorFlow.